# Calling a function inside a function in python

Tags: python

```
def function1(..):
    def inside(..):
        content
    return ...

def function2(..):
```

Inside the function2 I need to use the function 'inside'. The function 'inside' can be defined outside the scope of function1 and used in as many functions as wanted. But if I want to do it this way, how can it be done?

I am a novice programmer. So a simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Since the scope of function "inside" is function1, you will not be able to access it from function 2.

Comment: You should think of using classes if you need functionality like this.

Answer (score 2):

One reason I can see this being wanted is if you want `function1` to be able to *configure* `inside`, so `function2`’s output changes depending on how you called `function1` before. You could do this by storing the function in the outer scope and updating it within `function1`:

```
>>> commonFunction = None
>>> def function1 (someParam):
        def inside (x):
            return '{} {}'.format(someParam, x)
        global commonFunction
        commonFunction = inside

>>> def function2 (y):
        print('Foo', commonFunction(y))

>>> function1('bar')
>>> function2('baz')
Foo bar baz
>>> function1('Hello')
>>> function2('World')
Foo Hello World
```

However, since that involves using `global`, I would advise against it. It would be clearer to just return `inside` in `function1` and explicitely replace `commonFunction` with it. And you might want to consider passing the function to `function2` too to make it clear that it depends on another function that is not within its own control. For example:

```
commonFunction = function1('bar')
function2('baz', commonFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason that something like this won't work?

```
def function1():
    inside()

def function2():
    inside()

def inside():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. It cannot be done. By defining the function `inside` inside `function1`, you restrict its scope to `function1`. If you want to use it in `function2`, why define `inside` inside `function1` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use `func_code` and the module `types`:

```
import types

co = function1.func_code
modified_consts = list(co.co_consts)
# [None, <code object inside at 0000000001D47EB0, file "E:\Proyectos\Eclipse\Python\Test\__init__.py", line 2>, 'from function1']

# Search an element which is from type 'CodeType'
inside = None
for e in modified_consts:
    if isinstance(e, types.CodeType):
        inside = types.FunctionType(e, function1.func_globals)
        break

inside()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24321180/3240679) for this but in general this should be avoided. And one of the reasons you just provided above. The "proper" way would be to use classes.

```
class My_class():
    def function1(self):
        self.inside()
    def inside(self):
        print "Hi!"
def function2():
    My_class.inside()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you want to be doing. However one solution is to have function1 return its inner function.

```
def function1():
    def inside():
        print 'hei'
    return inside

def function2():
    function1()() # Note the double parentheses as we're calling the return value
```